# TypeError: $ is not a function in AureliaBootstrapDatepicker.attached

Tags: aurelia, bootstrap-datepicker

[The thrown error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yEIO.png)

I am adding the plugin in main.js:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging()
        .plugin('aurelia-bootstrap-datepicker');
```

and in my foo.html i am using the following code:

```
 <bootstrap-datepicker value.bind="'mm-dd-yyyy'" dp-options.bind="dpOptions" changedate.delegate="dateChanged($event)"></bootstrap-datepicker>
```

I'm also using skeleton-navigation-esnext skeleton. I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Seems like there is a missing jQuery dependency

Comment: @bluevoodoo1 it works perfectly in base router views, but the error is thrown in child-router views